# Request time out error

Tags: networking, httpwebrequest, network-protocols

Today i came across strange problem whenever i try to pingging to my server works properly but
whenever i send http reuest from browser the request time out happens.

can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your web server is not responding. Is it doing fine? Check if it is listening on the 80 port. (default HTTP port). If browser can connect to port 80 and you still get time out error - that means that web-application running on web server has some problems handling your request.

Ping works because it uses low level ICMP protocol. Ping can be used to check if host on the network is available.